# Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory

I know this issue has been brought up many times before on stack overflow but none of the answers I've found seem to fix my problem. I'm working in InelliJ IDEA Community Edition. When I try to compile my project, I get the error: `Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.` However, my project is only 72.2 MB. Also, I have "-Xmx1g" in my vmoptions. When I go to change my memory settings, they are already at 1024MiB:
[image]

If I try to make this any lower than 256, it says "The value should be greater than 256" and it won't let me.
I have a 64 bit java installation:
[image]
I have 32.0G RAM, with 31.7G usable, and I'm on a 64-bit OS.
I installed Gradle as some people suggested but that didn't help. And I made sure that my java home path environment was pointing to the same place as intelliJ is for my project. Please let me know if anyone has any other ideas I can try! Thanks!

Comment: Which JDK is your project using, that's the important attribute, not the JDK that you are using to run idea. (File, Project structure..., Project settings, SDK)

Comment: The heap size for the compiler is set in File, Settings..., "Build, Execution, Deployment", Compiler, "User-local build process heap size"

Comment: The JDK my project is using is the same as my java home. Also I've set the User local build process heap size to 700 mb and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Set lower heap size i IDE compiler settings: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | **Shared build process heap size (Mbytes):**.

Comment: This is set to 700, and I still get the same error